# Understanding the idea of a dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm stuck on a few ideas from Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra text Sec 3.5.

Let $V$ be a finite vector space over a field $F$ and let $f$ be a linear 
transformation $f: V \to F$.

There are a few properties I'm trying to work through.   In particular, the ideas at the bottom of page 98 continuing on to page 9:

[image: bottom p98]

[image: top p99]

Where I'm stuck is the following.  If I have a vector space $V$.  Let's say $V$ has basis $B=\{\beta_1,...,\beta_k\}.$  Then for a vector $v$ we have $v=\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i\beta_i$.

Would it be accurate to say that $f(v)=f(\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i\beta_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_if_i(\beta_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i$

Comment: Only if $f(\beta_i)=1$ always.

Comment: The letter $c_i$ is used for multiple conflicting things here. Equation (3-12) states that $f = \sum_i c_i f_i$, but then you have written $v = \sum_i c_i \beta_i$.

Comment: @littleO I see that now.  That's my fault with sloppy notation . What I'm trying to see is what happens when I take a vector in $V$ which is a linear combination of scalars and basis elements and it gets mapped into a field $F$.  Now I'm not sure how to demonstrate that symbolically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you denota as $c$ is actually denoted as $\alpha$ in the text, so I will use that notation:

Let $\{\alpha_i\}_i$ a basis of the vector space $V$, the dual basis will be denoted $\{f_i\}_i$. Then for the vector $v=\sum_i a_i \alpha_i$ we get:

$$f(v)=f(\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i\alpha_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_if(\alpha_i)$$

However, now we can expand $f$ in the dual basis: $f=\sum_j c_j f_j$.

Then 
$$f(v) =  \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_if(\alpha_i) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{k}a_i c_jf_j(\alpha_i)= \sum_{i,j=1}^{k}c_j a_i\delta_{ij} = \sum_i c_ia_i. $$

Comment: I believe it was mentioned in the comments above, but is it true that $f$ has to be a specifically chosen function such that $f(\alpha_i)=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: No, $f$ is an arbitrary function, i.e. an element of the dual space. The elements of the dual basis (which are unfortunately denoted $f_j$ here) are defined such that $f_j(\alpha_i) = \delta_{ij}$